# How to change the color of the main bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I'm learning to make the sliding menu ( drawer )

I've tried using various solutions of other friends in the group , but none of them worked.

I can change all the colors of the layout in my app , except the color of the top bar (main ) . I would put the color # 1674d3 as the bottom of the main bar. Any friend can help me solve this?

My coding was based on this tutorial: 
Click [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzueP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API level 11 or greater or Lesser API [level](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
             // only for HoneyComb and newer versions
            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

            // title;
            bar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>Home</font>"));

            //Rgb for yellow.
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(255,215,0)));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Nambi. How can I change the font by following your idea of ​​coding? The font that I want to put is already inside the assets folder is the source agency_fb. Can you help me?